# Need Free jQuery Slider for commercial use with content and thumnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jquery-slider

I am looking for am slider which is almost similar in functionality as show in this 
[LINK](http://wowslider.com/jquery-image-scroller-prime-time-linear-demo.html). I have look for some but most of them are not free. I would appreciate if someone could point me to a slider which is similar to what is show in example with image fade effect & flexibility to put thumbnail on left or right side of image.

I can also work on a free script which i can alter to get the desired results.

[image: Slider]

Answer (score 2):

I have always used the jQuery [Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) plugin.

[Here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager2.html) you can see how to make the thumbnails with it.

It's as easy as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
    });
});
```

and is really lightweight.

Comment: Fine i can work to change the thumbnail image position but how can i add scroll bar effect to thumbnails as in the actual example. It doesnt show how to add title & description in any of the examples

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker Each slide could have the title and image simply positioned over the image, however you want. The thumbnails could also be injected into any element, including one with a height that allowed scrolling to see additional thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the free version of the same WoW slider from the Download Page:

[**Download**](http://wowslider.com/wowslider-free-setup.zip)

Even if you want to use a commercial one. you can get a discount on the same slider purchase

> *   Stop! Instant $20 Discount!   ***
>
> Order WOW Slider Unlimited Websites Business License now and save $20!
>   $20 OFF Unlimited Websites License NOTE: the links are valid for 48
>   hours only. See also License Comparison

Comment: that is free for only non commercial use only. I CAN USE IT IF I GOT IT RIHT